# Proof that two different basis are orthonormal to each other in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I'm solving the following problem:

> Let $B=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ and $C=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,2), (2,-1)\}$ two basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $C$ is orthonormal to B.

I know that $C$ is orthonormal. My solution was:

1. Normalize B's vectors:
   $$
   \hat{u}=\frac{\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}=\frac{(1,2)}{\sqrt{5}}\\
   \hat{v}=\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}=\frac{(3,4)}{5}\\
   $$
2. Calculate the dot product between each vector in $B$ with each other in $C$.
   $$
   \hat{u}\cdot \vec{w}=\frac{1}{5}(1+4)=1\\
   \hat{u}\cdot \vec{k}=\frac{1}{5}(2-2)=0\\
   \hat{v}\cdot \vec{w}=\frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}(3\cdot 1+4\cdot 2)=\frac{11}{5\sqrt{5}}\\
   \hat{v}\cdot \vec{k}=\frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}(6-4)=\frac{2}{5\sqrt{5}}\\
   $$

My question is: If the answer says that C is orthonormal to B, shouldn't all dot products in [2] be zero? What is the definition of a basis being orthonormal to another in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to be confused. There is no standard definition for one basis to be orthonormal to another. I cannot see any reason at all for those two bases to be called orthogonal to each other, let alone orthonormal.